# Associate or save relationship only works when nullable in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I can't find where is the explanation when associate or save a model in laravel only works when the foreign key is set to nullable, otherwise gives me Integrity constraint violation: 1452. I assume that make a foreign key null its a bad practice, most if i have to working with one to many relationships.

Example

```
$lugarCompra = Input::get('lugar_compra');
$lugarCompra = Lugares_compra::find($lugarCompra);

$tipoPago    = Input::get('tipo_pago');
$tipoPago    = Tipos_pago::find($tipoPago);

$origen      = Input::get('origen');

$fecha_embarque = Input::get('fecha_embarque');
$fecha_embarque = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_embarque));

$hora_embarque  = Input::get('hora_embarque');

$ordenDeCompra = Ordenes_compra::create(array(
                        'lugar_origen' => $origen,
                        'fecha_embarque' => $fecha_embarque,
                        'hora_embarque' => $hora_embarque,
));

$ordenDeCompra->save();

// THIS NOT WORKING, GIVES ME INTEGRITY CONSTRAINT VIOLATION.
$ordenDeCompra = $lugarCompra->ordenesCompra()->save($ordenDeCompra);
$ordenDeCompra = $tipoPago->ordenesCompra()->save($ordenDeCompra);

// THIS ALSO NOT WORKS, GIVES ME INTEGRITY CONSTRAINT...
$ordenDeCompra->lugar_compra()->associate($lugarCompra)->save();
$ordenDeCompra->tipo_pago()->associate($formaPago)->save();
```

And yes, the parent tables has data so thats not the problem. Only works if the foreign key is nullable(), what is the best way to do this?? Nullable seems a hack to me...
Tnx for the replies...

Comment: Show the error. And no, nullable FK is not a bad practice, depends on business needs. Your problem is not nullable field or not, but wrong data passed to the `INSERT` statement  - most likely you don't want to pass `null` there, but you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that making the foreign key nullable is a hack in this situation, but it would depend on your data.

In my project, I have a model `User` and a model `Client`. A `User` may be an administrator for at most one `Client`, but they could also be a regular user, who is not an administrator. This is a one-to-many relationship, so I add a client_id foreign key to the users table.

The client_id is not always set, and is actually null for the majority of users.

I think this is similar to your situation (I can't tell exactly because of the language in your code). If you are representing an *optional*, one-to-many relationship, then a nullable foreign key is a perfectly acceptable representation.

Comment: thanx for the reply... i do research, and yes its not a bad practice after all, as you said it depends on the logic... my question was about the process to create a relationship in laravel...