# Save new non-nullable relationship using Laravel ORM abstraction without database integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

This question pertains to Laravel 7.

I have two models, let's say Post and Comment, in a typical one-to-many relationship. Both the relationship and its inverse are defined. When making the migrations for their database tables, I did NOT make the `post_id` on the Comment table nullable. I figured making it non-nullable is a reasonable constraint, since all Comments must logically be attached to a Post.

However it seems I can't use the `create()`, `save()` etc to associate relationship when making new Comment. I would like to do something like:

```php
$post->comments()->create(["text" => "Comment text goes here"]);
```

I would assume that this would create the Comment with the `post_id` filled in, but alas, it throws an "integrity constraint violation" on database level (post_id cannot be null)

Similarly, I tried:

```php
$comment = new Comment(["text" => "Comment text goes here"]); 
$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Same thing - database integrity constraint violation. But... why? I would expect Laravel not to only make one INSERT operation which includes the `post_id`, when creating this Comment. In both cases I don't expect the new Comment to be inserted with `post_id` being null.

I know I could manually set `post_id` to the primary key when creating, and will do so if there's truly no other option - I prefer to use ORM abstractions when possible.

Questions:

- Does anyone know if `save()`, `create()`, actually INSERT the row first with the relationship field being null and then UPDATE it afterwards - or am I just doing something wrong?
- What's the correct way to do this with Eloquent ORM abstraction, if possible?
- I always felt that, since I defined a relationship `post()` on Comment, it is now bad practice to explicitly handle `post_id` column if I'm using the ORM, since it defeats the point of the relationship abstraction. Is this philosophy sound, have I got the right idea?

NOTE: I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104973/associate-or-save-relationship-only-works-when-nullable-in-laravel) exists, but I argue mine is not a duplicate because, in that question, their belongsTo relationship was optional, so they accepted the answer of "just remove the DB constraint / make the column nullable". Mine is not an optional field so it does not make sense to make it nullable. Yes, changing the DB constraint would "fix" the issue but I prefer to keep the integrity constraint since Comments with post_id=null would be a glitch, so it's ideal to make that impossible on the DB level imo.

Comment: is `$post` an existing model instance?

Comment: @lagbox I was going to answer yes, but I think you just figured it out. In the code I used to test this, $post is existing model instance but I tried to associate comment before I ever called save() on $post. So of course $post does not have a primary key yet. Thank you for catching that :O

Comment: @lagbox If you want to add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `$post` is an "existing" model instance. If this is a new instance make sure to save it, so it will have an 'id' from the database, otherwise the 'id' would be `null` that it tries to assign to the related record's foreign key field.